# Issue with Magento 2 generated sitemap.xml

Tags: magento2, category, url, product-urls, sitemaps

I'm using Magento's built in sitemap generation tool and have it set to generated nightly. The issue I'm facing with it is that the urls in the sitemap do not match the ones found on the site.

To clarify, the urls I'm seeing in the sitemap match Magento's default url scheme; **/catalog/category/view/id/4667** rather than the SEO friendly one's that look like **/snow/fashion/outerwear.html**.

Aside from the obvious SEO hit, this is also affecting our cache warmer that uses this sitemap to crawl the site since it is hitting and warming the wrong urls.

It is probably worthwhile to mention that both the links resolve to the same page, but I want the nice urls in the sitemap. Also this is happening for both products and categories.

Any ideas on what could be causing this would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you specify your Magento version?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh sure, its Magento CE 2.2.1

Comment: @DanielBlack  any solution on this ?

Comment: @TirthPatel, I was using an extension to generate the friendly URL's nightly ([Oleg Koval's regenerate url](https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites)) which deleted all the friendly URLs and reloaded. The sitemap was being generated at this time and did not have the friendly urls to add. This was a pretty specific issue so I'm not sure this answer will help you at all but maybe just verify the rewrites are in the 'url_rewrites' table at the time of sitemap generation.

Comment: okay thanks @DanielBlack